# copyWith in ThemeData not work in MaterialApp

Tags: flutter

how to use fontFamily with copyWith in ThemeData or how to fix my below error ?

```
   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Consumer2<ThemeNotifier, SettingNotifier>(builder:
            (context, ThemeNotifier theme, SettingNotifier settings, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            theme: theme.getTheme().copyWith(
                  textTheme: theme.getTheme()
                      .textTheme
                      .apply(fontFamily: settings.getFontSetting()),
                ),
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: MainHomePage(),
          );
        });
      }
    }
```

Theme Data Class how to add fontFamily in theme data or text theme in copyWith i want to add textTheme with copyWith in MaterialApp to getFonts
anyone can solve this problem ..........................................

```
class ThemeNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData _themeData;
  ThemeData getTheme() => _themeData;

  ThemeNotifier() {
    ThemeManager.readData('themeMode').then((value) {
      print('App Theme value read from storage: ' + value.toString());
      var themeMode = value;

      if (themeMode == 'yellow') {
        _themeData = yellow;
      } else {
        if (themeMode == 'red') {
          _themeData = red;
        } else {
          if (themeMode == 'green') {
            _themeData = green;
          } else {
            _themeData = orange;
          }
        }
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  void setOrangeTheme() async {
    _themeData = orange;
    ThemeManager.saveData('themeMode', 'orange');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setRedTheme() async {
    _themeData = red;
    ThemeManager.saveData('themeMode', 'red');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setYellowTheme() async {
    _themeData = yellow;
    ThemeManager.saveData('themeMode', 'yellow');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setGreenTheme() async {
    _themeData = green;
    ThemeManager.saveData('themeMode', 'green');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! When adding a question, you should add as much information as you currently have, so it would be helpful if you add some context on what error you get, what's returned from `theme.getTheme()` and so on.

Comment: thanks, theme.getTheme() = ThemeData i use for change app theme with shared preferences

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: The method 'copyWith' was called a null.

Comment: So it means that your ThemeNotifier is null at this point. You should provide more details on the notifier and where you provide it.

Comment: bro check ThemeNotifier class how to use getFontSetting in getTheme

Answer (score 0):

**check. this**

```
 ThemeData _buildDarkTheme() {
  final baseTheme = ThemeData(fontFamily: "Sunflower",);
    return baseTheme.copyWith(
   brightness: Brightness.dark,
     primaryColor: Colors.grey[800],
  accentColor: Colors.grey[850]);
}
```

*then do this as i apply it to my app as follows:*

```
   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new MaterialApp(
    theme: _buildDarkTheme(),
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar: _buildAppBar(),
      body: new Container(
        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        height: double.infinity,
        child:.....
```

Comment: this getTheme()

Comment: class ThemeNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData _themeData;
  ThemeData getTheme() => _themeData;

  ThemeNotifier() {
    ThemeManager.readData('themeMode').then((value) {
      print('App Theme value read from storage: ' + value.toString());
      var themeMode = value;

Comment: if (themeMode == 'yellow') {
        _themeData = yellow;
      } else {
        if (themeMode == 'red') {
          _themeData = red;
        } else {
          if (themeMode == 'green') {
            _themeData = green;
          } else {
            _themeData = orange;
          }
        }
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

Comment: void setOrangeTheme() async {
    _themeData = orange;
    ThemeManager.saveData('themeMode', 'orange');
    notifyListeners();
  }